# Can't install Flutter Application on Smartphone

Tags: android, flutter, dart, adb

I'm a beginner, so sorry if this is a dump question.

If i try to debug my App using my Smartphone i get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Mi 9T Pro in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install G:\Apps\valorant\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.phillip.valorguide signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
Error launching application on Mi 9T Pro.
Exited (sigterm)
```

**It worked at first.**

How can i solve this issue? I dont have the app installed anymore so i dont know how it cannot match with a previous installed Version.

Comment: Could you add flutter doctor output?

Answer (score -1):

it seems like you have changed the package name.

i also had this error and solved it by uninstalling the app from the device and trying again.

Comment: The Problem is I already uninstalled it and still get this error.